# Unicode entity in menu item of wheelnav.js library (using under the hood raphael.js) [SVG]

Tags: javascript, svg, unicode, raphael, wheelnav.js

Since wheelnav.js libray allows programmer to define menu item as text or image. Never both at the same time for one menu element, and I need icon + text I came up with encoding icon as a unicode entity, which is not difficult forasmuch as I use Font Awesome.

Unfortunately from what I understood from wheelnav.js source code, underlying raphael.js when creating SVG text node (and its tspan child) escapes special characaters and changes & to &amp; resulting in entity being displayed literally instead of corresponding icon.

The only solution I came up with is to copypaste character(icon) from Font Awesome website to title string. It works, in the browser I can see an icon, but in my IDE I just see rectangle.
It makes it unclear and nonreadable to other developers and I can't expect them to install Font Awesome in their IDEs.

Is there any other clever way to prevent wheelnav.js (raphael.js) from escaping special characters or any other solution to my problem?

```
 var icons = {
        'key': '&#xf084;',
        'cogs': '&#xf085;',
        'connection': '' //copypasting character, that would work.
     };

var items = [ {title: icons.key + 'Security'},
              {title: icons.cogs + 'Settings'},
              {title: icons.connection + 'Connection'} ];

var piemenu = new wheelnav('main_menu');
piemenu.initWheel(items.map(function(item){
                                        return item.title;
                                    }));
piemenu.createWheel();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swiatek7/t08udf7m/10/)

How it looks like:

[image: How it looks like]

How it should look like:

[image: How it should look like]

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using HTML entities, or the character directly, you could try using JS unicode  character literals.

```
var icons = {
   'key':  '\uf084',
   'cogs': '\uf085',
   ...
};
```